# What does a # sign after a % sign in a scanf() function mean?

Tags: c, input, scanf, format-specifiers

What does the following code mean,in C

```
scanf("%d%#d%d",&a,&b,&c);
```

if given values `1 2 3` it gives output as `1 0 0`

P.S- I know it is used with `printf()` statement but here in `scanf()` statement it gives random behaviour.

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the `#` only used in `printf`? I thought it was used to prepend `0` to octal numbers and `0x` to hex

Comment: Can't find it in any `scanf` man page. I guess you should have a warning telling you there's no such modifier. Do you compile with warnings? And indeed @Levi, [printf man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) shows `#` modifier

Comment: it works in gcc compiler in the scanf()

Comment: @FossArduino: What version of gcc are you using? On mine (4.9.2) I get warnings

Comment: And what does it *return*? Probably `1`, meaning only the first conversion succeeded, and thus that `b` and `c` are not initialized.

Comment: Just tried with `gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)`, it compiling without any errors.
While executing with inputs 1,2,3.

After just the first 2 inputs (1,2) it displays 

`home/user/> ./a.out
1
2
0x0.02aaa00000001p-1022%b`

Comment: @Levi im using gcc version 4.8.2

Comment: @unwind it prints 1 ,0,0 for a ,b and c

Comment: @FossArduino Yes, that's in the question text. What I meant was what the `scanf()` call returns. It's a function, it has a (non-`void`) return value that tells you how many conversions succeeded. If it's less than you expect, you can't rely on the contents of the destination variables.

Comment: @FossArduino gcc is a compiler, not an implementation of the libc! gcc does not supply the `scanf` function!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR;** - A `#` after a `%` sign in the format string of `scanf()` function is wrong code.

*Explanation:*

The `#` here is a *flag* character, which is allowed in `fprintf()` and family, not in `fscanf()` and family.

In case of your code, the presence of `#` after `%` is treated as *invalid conversion specifier*. As per 7.21.6.2,

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined

So, your code produces [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

*Hint: you can check the `return` value of `scanf()` to check how many elements were "scanned" successfully.*

---

However, FWIW, using `#` with `%d` in `printf()` also is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Just for reference: As per the `C11` standard document , chapter §7.21.6.1, flag characters part, (emphasis mine)

> #
>
> The result is converted to an ‘‘alternative form’’. For `o` conversion, it increases the precision, if and only if necessary, to force the first digit of the result to be a zero (if the value and precision are both `0`, a single `0` is printed). For `x` (or `X`) conversion, a nonzero result has `0x` (or `0X`) prefixed to it. For `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversions, the result of converting a floating-point number always contains a decimal-point character, even if no digits follow it. (Normally, a decimal-point character appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit follows it.) For `g` and `G` conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the
>   result. **For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: doesn't §7.21.6.1 apply to `printf` instead of `scanf`?

Comment: What you are quoting from standard is for printf family functions, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Wimmel Sorry, I edited to make the answer proper. I'm not a native english speaker, so somtimes i mess up.

Comment: @BlueMoon Updated my answer, please see above comment. Thanks for pointing out the confusing part. :-)

Comment: maybe this is the reason ,i didn't got any error so was confused.

Comment: @FossArduino No, my answer was a bit wrong. I have updated. Please check now.

Comment: @FossArduino Right you are. :-)

Comment: @dear (anonymous) downvoter, thanks for your downvote. It helped me notice my mistake. Corrected it. IMHO, it could not have been batter if you would have left a small note, 'coz sometimes it's difficult to cath self-errors. . Thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2), the use of `#` is illegal.

[Its use makes your program invoke Undefined Behaviour](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p13).

Of course, if **your implementation** defines it, it is defined behaviour **for your implementation** and it does what **your documentation** says.

Comment: [If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p13)